# как вытащить текст из .doc или .docx на Java?

Tags: java, текст, doc, docx

Я хочу вытащить текст из .doc или .docx с таким же шрифтом , размером на Джаве. Но пока что у меня не получается даже просто вытащить текст. Я попробовала множество вариантов, но везде ответ выходит с кубиками.

Используется следующий код:

```
package myconverter;

import com.itextpdf.text.Anchor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.CMYKColor;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Myconverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException, IOException {
        String result = "";
        String line;
        String doc = "C:\\samples\\HelloWorld.doc";
        String pdf = doc.substring(0, doc.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) + "pdf";
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdf));
        document.open();
        Anchor anchorTarget = new Anchor("");
        anchorTarget.setName("BackToTop");
        Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
        //  paragraph1.setSpacingBefore(50);
        paragraph1.add(anchorTarget);
        document.add(paragraph1);
        File file = new File(doc);
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                result = line;
               // System.out.println(result);  
                //document.add(new Paragraph(result, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 14, Font.BOLD,new CMYKColor(0, 255, 0, 0))));
                document.add(new Paragraph(result));
            }
        }
        //  System.out.println(result);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит "с таким же шрифтом, размером"? В каком формате? rtf?

Comment: И куда вы его вставляете?

Comment: я просто делаю конвертер с word на pdf. и я хотела сначала вытащить текст из ворда потом присвоить к переменному, а потом записать это в пдф

Comment: Скажите тогда какие библиотеки используете для чтения из word и записи в pdf, посмотрю какие там функции для настройки стиля. Но да, лучше если и свой код покажете (именно где копируете стиль текста).

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim со стилем я еще не занималась, решила пока просто вытащить текст только потом...

Comment: Так зачем сюда, добавьте в сам вопрос, тут же это в кашу превратилось.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim   извиняюсь я здесь впервые задаю вопрос. Добавила в ответы

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim     а вообще вроде бы для работы с ПДФ  нужна библиотека iText, а для ворда Apache POI

Comment: Попробуйте создать [МСВП](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Добавьте код в вопрос (под текстом вопроса есть ссылка «править»), укажите содержимое входного файла и что Вы получили на выходе.

Answer (score 2):

Ну FileReader для этого точно не предназначен, он предназначен для простых текстовых форматов, Word таковым не является.

Можно это сделать с помощью POI, но там много ручками таскать придется. Готовый код для этого я вам не дам, *но предложу легкий вариант (правда он не со всеми форматами ворда дружит): вот есть такая [библиотека](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/releases), которая кроме всего прочего может docx (xml версию) конвертировать в pdf.* (Данный кусок текста не имеет отношения к примеру)

Вот пример использования:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.samples.docx.converters.Data;

public class ConvertDocxBigToPDF
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try
        {
            // 1) Load docx with POI XWPFDocument
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument( Data.class.getResourceAsStream( "DocxBig.docx" ) );

            // 2) Convert POI XWPFDocument 2 PDF with iText
            File outFile = new File( "target/DocxBig.pdf" );
            outFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( outFile );
            PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create().fontEncoding( "windows-1251" );
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert( document, out, options );
        }
        catch ( Throwable e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println( "Generate DocxBig.pdf with " + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime ) + " ms." );
    }
}
```

Comment: Точно `windows-1250`, а не `windows-1251`?

Comment: Подправил. Пример из репозитория.

Comment: можно подробнее про библио import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.samples.docx.converters.Data;?

Comment: Честно, сам я с ней не работал. Просто в архиве переписок iText ее советовали. (был другой вариант, но он платный) По сути она предназначена для генерации отчетов, И кроме этого еще может проводить конвертацию в PDF. Тут только методом тыка разбираться. (ссылка на не в ответе есть)

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim я нашла этот код в интернете по ссылке http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=xdocreport-demo/samples/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.samples.docx.converters/src/fr/opensagres/xdocreport/samples/docx/converters/pdf/ConvertDocxBigToPDF.java    Data оказался отдельным классом. Но там он пустой. Не могли бы вы посоветовать что нужно туда написать?

Comment: Это может быть любой произвольный класс. Можете поменять на сам ConvertDocxBigToPDF. PS Только взглянул на этот пример в здравом состоянии, сразу понял что библиотека тут не затрагивается ни коим образом. <_>

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim  теперь ругается на метод  getInstance  на линии XWPF2PDFViaITextConverter.getInstance().convert( document, out, options );

Comment: А что пишет? Добавьте в вопрос текст ошибки.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim   метод на который указывает ссылка, использует недоступный тип: org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.IXWPFConverter<org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions>